# Modernizr Html5 Validation

Tags: jquery, html, modernizr

I made a form with the required atribute for html5 validation and everything worked fine if I submit with my `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`.
So because not all browser are compatibles with html I tried Modernizr.
So I made a script with Jquery to validate the fields if the inputs don't have the required attribute. I changed the button

> type="submit"

for

> type="button"

and made my script:

```
$("#submit_form").click(function(){
    var val = 0;
    if(!Modernizr.input.required){
        $("#contact_form input,#contact_form select").each(function(){
            if($.trim($(this).val()) === ""){
                $(this).parent("div").addClass("has-error");
                val++;
            }
        });
        if(val > 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("#contact_form").submit();
});
```

The script works fine and validate the fields and add the **"has-error"** class to my form elements.
The problem is when the browser accept the **required attribute** and submit the form, html5 doesn't validate anymore the form. 
It only work if **the button type is "submit"**.

So what can I do to validate with my script if the browser doesn't accept the required attribute, and if it does, validate with Html5.

Thank you

Comment: why are you changing the type of the button to `button`? You can still cancel the onsubmit event the same way you are the click event

Comment: yes, I did it that way, I didn't know I could do that. It's working perfect.
Thanks!

Comment: But I don't know why the form not validate with html5 if I submit it by Jquery